# Access VBA: Expression builder: SUMIF invalid syntax

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to add a calculated field in the table `[Progetti]`. In this field, I would like to have a SUMIF from the table `[Fatture]` where `Fatture![Codice Progetto] = Progetti![Codice Progetto]`.

For this purpose, in the expression builder, I wrote the following expression but the syntax seems to not be correct.

```
=DSum("Fatture![Fattura]","[Fatture]","Fatture![Codice Progetto] = Progetti![Codice Progetto]")
```

This makes me wonder: is it a good practice to apply a SUMIF in a table or should I use a query? I would like to don't use the query because there are other fields that have to be editable and I don't want to switch any time from table to query.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Always use a query. Calculated fields will only cause you troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You cant apply what you want in a calculated field because the result of your expression is one number for the whole table. But a calculated field is applied on each row.

What you need is a query

```
SELECT Sum(Fatture) As SumFatture FROM Progetti WHERE [Codice Progetto] = [Codice Progetto]
```

Comment: yes but what I need is that the expression is applied on each row: for each 'Progetti![Codice Progetto]' execute the SUMIF

Comment: Querys are applied on each row. Can you maybe post how your tabales look? With the columns and values? Its hard to know what you exactly what without the table structures